# Access Denied: Request access form rejected

Tags: linkedin-api

We applied for an application with the Community Management API. Later, we received a mail from LinkedIn with the message "Access Denied: Request access form rejected".

LinkedIn have a help page with error messages explained, but this message wasn’t included there.

We contacted LinkedIn support desk who neither couldn’t/wouldn’t answer what’s wrong nor explain this message. Anybody who have a clue on this where LinkedIn fail?

Comment: Your contractual arrangements with LinkedIn aren't really a programming problem. Even if this was on topic, we know nothing about what you put on the application that might cause LinkedIn to reject it.

Comment: I agree with you, this isn’t a programming problem. However LinkedIn support urged me twice to use this channel and states: “In an effort to boost support for our developer community, we moved our online support forum from the Developers site to StackOverflow.”

Comment: So to “support” their developer community they removed their support team and told people to get free help from third parties? Gosh. LinkedIn are scum.

Answer (score 0):

Have had the same issue.
Rejected twice, the first said they couldn’t verify the company (obviously never heard of companies house), the second just says Form Rejected.
Helpful!

As a note they also don’t respond to their support requests if you ask why.

Comment: Hello have the same issue; have you resolved your access please?